# MySQL SUM() Subquery with MIN()

Tags: mysql, sum, min

First of all here what i'm trying to accomplish:

Get the sum of `etp_product.price` and `option_price`.

```
SELECT 
  etp_product.product_id,
  etp_product.price,
  (SELECT MIN(price) AS FIELD_2 FROM etp_product_option_value pov WHERE pov.product_id = etp_product.product_id) AS option_price
FROM
  etp_product
GROUP BY
  etp_product.product_id,
  etp_product.price
```

I've tried this:

```
SELECT 
  etp_product.product_id,
  etp_product.price,
  (SELECT MIN(price) AS FIELD_2 FROM etp_product_option_value pov WHERE pov.product_id = etp_product.product_id) AS option_price,
SUM(etp_product.price + option_price) AS Total
FROM
  etp_product
GROUP BY
  etp_product.product_id,
  etp_product.price
```

But get this error:

> Unknown column 'option_price' in 'field list'

Any Idea how it could be done ?

Comment: The only time an alias can be referred to within its own select statement is in an "order by."  Otherwise, you have to perform the calculation again as with Bert Evans' answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
etp_product.product_id,
  etp_product.price,
  (SELECT MIN(price) AS FIELD_2 FROM etp_product_option_value pov WHERE pov.product_id = etp_product.product_id) AS option_price,
 etp_product.price + (SELECT MIN(price) AS FIELD_3 FROM etp_product_option_value pov WHERE pov.product_id = etp_product.product_id) AS Total
FROM
  etp_product
GROUP BY
  etp_product.product_id,
  etp_product.price
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer ... it does work but I get some NULL result from etp_product_option_value. As sometimes I have option and sometimes I don't.

Comment: So, in some cases, etp_product_option_value has no match to the product_id?  Does the query make sense in those cases?

Comment: ifnull will do the thing !  ifnull(MIN(price), '0') Thanks Bert !

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
  p.product_id,
  p.price,
  IFNULL(MIN(pv.price), 0) as option_price,
  (p.price + IFNULL(MIN(pv.price), 0)) as total
FROM etp_product p
JOIN etp_product_option_value pv ON WHERE pv.product_id = p.product_id
GROUP BY
  p.product_id,
  p.price
```

Comment: JOINs are virtually always better than a subquery in the SELECT!